# text file reading in c#

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text file, its the content from a mail body.it includes html codes.

I want to take only href tags from that text file.I want to do this with asp.net c# web application.

Does any one have a code to help me ...

Thanks

Comment: there's no such thing as `href` tags. Perhaps you mean `<a>` tags? Or `<a>` tags having an href attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to parse the HTML from your email and extract the *href* attributes from <a> tags.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(emailBody);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
   HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
   string href = att.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expression even though it is not a perfect solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\test.htm");

        Regex regex = new Regex("href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);
        foreach(Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and quick, not the the regex is perhaps more legible as `@"href\s*=\s*""([^""]*)"""` (or perhaps not, on second thought ;-) and that attributes can have apostrophes as delimiters as well as quotes?